# Trying to concatenate two span fields that use Knockoutjs

Tags: c#, knockout.js

I have just started using knockout.js and I am getting good results, but I have a small issue:

I have a list that is in JSON that I am using to build my template:

The following is the list and the code to formulate the list:

```
 public IEnumerable<dynamic> TheaterList { get; set; }
        List<TheaterTest> theaters = new List<TheaterTest>(); 

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                getTheaters();
                TheaterList = theaters;
            }

        }

        protected void getTheaters()
        {
            theaters.Add(new TheaterTest()
            {
                theater_dist = "3",
                theater_name = "Regal Webster Place 11",
                theater_add1 = "1471 W. Webster Ave",
                theater_add2 = "",
                theater_city = "Chicago",
                theater_state = "Il",
                theater_postcode = "60614",
                theater_phone = "(762) 711-9180"
            });

            theaters.Add(new TheaterTest()
            {
                theater_dist = "4.2",
                theater_name = "Regal Washington Park 9",
                theater_add1 = "1341 W Webster Ave",
                theater_add2 = "",
                theater_city = "Chicago",
                theater_state = "Il",
                theater_postcode = "60614",
                theater_phone = "(762) 711-9180"
            });
```

this is the code to build the JSON in .ascx

```
<script>
    var d = {};
    d.theaterList = <%= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TheaterList) %>  ;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        ko.applyBindings(new theaterSel.TheaterModel(d.theaterList));

    });
</script>
```

and here is my template:

```
<div class="theatre-info">
            <div class="theater-name">

                <a data-bind="attr: { href: ''}"><span class="theater-link" data-bind="    text: theater_name" /></a>

            </div>
            <div class="theatre-address" data-bind="text: theater_add1, text: theater_add2"></div>
            <div class="theatre-address" data-bind="text: theater_city + text: theater_state + text: theater_postcode"></div> 
            <div class="theatre-phone" data-bind="text: theater_phone"></div>
            <button>My Theatre</button>
        </div>
    </li>
```

I want to concatenate theater_city, theater_state, and theater_postcode: I think I can use "ko.compute ... but I am just not certain how to create that function. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track -

in your view model

```
var computedName = ko.computed(function () {
    return theater_city + ', ' + theater_state + ', ' + theater_postcode;
});
```

and in your view

```
<h1 data-bind="text: computedName"></h1>
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is what I thought but I didn't know how the function would know those values since they are coming from the JSON list. I actually coded something just like this. I just needed reassurance. Thank you so much!!